# Xaml string numeric format

Tags: xaml, string-formatting

how can I define a string format like this ?  **123.190,00** or **23,20** or **100,12** or **1.000,01**

I don't need a **currency** format or **ConverterCulture** format.

And  is it possible to insert the decimal point while the typing ?

Thank you very much

Comment: So actually you want some formatting in textbox, and you want the points to appear while the user types, right ?

Comment: Not so easy. Formatting is easy. Inserting the points requires some intelligence depending how long is the number. The more figures the user enters, the dots will move along, I am not sure it is very user friendly.

Comment: If your primary idea is to automatically insert the dots - I wouldn't. Or may be have many textboxes like in the Ip address textboxes

Comment: Just use a textbox control with "masking" already built in like the maskedtextbox in the extended toolkits.